# How to export favourites/bookmarks from Microsoft Edge?

Tags: microsoft-edge

How to export favourites/bookmarks from Microsoft Edge? Or does it not have this function? Thanks.

Answer (score 13):

Edge has a built-in export function, it's just hidden within the **import favorites** settings menu.

To export bookmarks from Edge (release 40.15) to a file:

- In the top right of the browser, click "..."
- Click "Settings"
- Click "Import from another browser"
- Click "Export to file" (yeah, I know it's not entirely intuitive considering the previous step mentions only "import")
  [image: screenshot of: “Export to file” button on settings menu]
- Now you should get a Save dialog with a default file name in the format of `Microsoft_Edge_‎dd_‎mm_‎yyyy.html`
- Save your bookmarks file to the desired folder

Comment: That doesn't exist anymore.

Comment: As of 2023, one needs to click "..." then "Favorites" (or Ctrl-Shift-O). Then in the appearing favorites pop-up again "..." and then "Export favorites".

Answer (score 4):

It is true that Edge does not have a native export function.  However, there is a 3rd-party application called EdgeManage that can both import and export an HTML-based "bookmarks.html" file.

EdgeManage is the successor to EdgeExport (which is still available, but somewhat deprecated)

http://www.emmet-gray.com/Articles/EdgeManage.html

PS: I am the author

Comment: Edge _does_ have a built-in export function.

Comment: Correct.... modern versions of Edge do have an export function.  This feature was added in build v1703 on 4/11/2017

Answer (score 3):

Kudos to Emmet Gray for the creating *The Export Edge Bookmarks Tool.*  He  shared both the code for power users and a simple .exe to extract favorites from the ESE database and export them to a standards-based "bookmark.htm" file. See www.emmet-gray.com/Articles/EdgeExport.html

Chrome and other browsers don't play nice with HTM files so you might need to convert to HTML.  I am sure there are many ways to do this but Adobe makes this easy for anyone.  Just use Acrobat (Arobat DC) to export to HTML

**Steps:**

- Close all Edge windows
- [.exe]: http://www.emmet-gray.com/Temp/SetupEdgeExport.exe "Click to save exe and install"

  or
- [ code]: http://www.emmet-gray.com/Files/ExamplesAndDemos/EdgeExport.zip/ "Click for code"
- Open saved htm file in Acrobat and export to html

Now you have HTML file that can be edited and imported into a browser that works

## **UPDATE**

**Thank you Firefox!  Mozilla Firefox Version 44.0.2 now allows direct import from Microsoft Edge.  Once in Firefox favorites can be exported to any browser.**

Answer (score 3):

To import and export from Microsoft Edge go to Microsoft Edge home page.

1. Under Microsoft Edge Home Page, you must click on any Primary Hyperlink, afterwards click on any story under Primary Hyperlink.
2. Click on the 3 dots … (more), about 9 items down, click on Open With Internet Explorer.
3. Under Internet Explorer click on 1st item named File
4. Go down to Import and Export about 14 items down and click
5. Here you can

   - import from another browser
   - Import from a file
   - Export to a file:

     - Favorites, Feeds, Cookies

I don’t know why all of these steps, but it works

But you cannot upload the exported file to Chrome.

Answer (score 0):

You can find your favorites in the AppData\Local directory. Simply create a backup of this directory.

```
%LOCALAPPDATA%\Packages\Microsoft.MicrosoftEdge_8wekyb3d8bbwe\AC\MicrosoftEdge\User\Default\Favorites
```

Unfortunately, this method of backing up bookmarks is pretty much useless, because you cannot re-import favorites in Edge just by adding files to this directory.

Comment: For backup purposes, you can have the OS sync those through OneDrive (in fact, it will do so by default, including to mobile devices). The trick is getting them into another browser. Not sure about that.

Answer (score 0):

Go to:

```
C:\Users\[USERNAME]\AppData\Local\Packages\Microsoft.MicrosoftEdge_8wekyb3d8bbwe\AC\MicrosoftEdge\User\Default\Favorites
```

Copy the links (aka favorites) to the folder `C:\Users\[USERNAME]\Favorites`

That's how you export them to Internet Explorer. If you want to export them to other browser, in IE there is "Export" function that will help you do that.

Answer (score 0):

I noticed that after November's Update it changed the way how bookmarks are stored. Now they are stored in a database file (Extensible Stored Engine), in this folder:

```
%LOCALAPPDATA%\Packages\Microsoft.MicrosoftEdge_8wekyb3d8bbwe\AC\MicrosoftEdge\User\Default\DataStore\Data\nouser1\120712-0049\DBStore\spartan.edb
```

I guy made an export tool that catches automatically that file, parses it, and exports to an html file importable in every other browser:

[Link](http://www.emmet-gray.com/Articles/EdgeExport.html)

Answer (score -1):

I was trying to export Edge bookmarks into Chrome. I looked through many links on this topic, and it doesn't look like Chrome has released an update that allows it to convert the Edge bookmarks. Of course MS ain't gonna make it easy for us either. However I found this app called Transmute. It seems to have done the trick for me. Download it, run it, and reboot your computer.

Comment: how it works?, improve.

Answer (score -1):

Links to the EdgeManage program were broken, these ones work:

[SetupEdgeManage (installer)](http://www.emmet-gray.com/Files/Applications/SetupEdgeManage.exe)

[EdgeManage (no installer, portable)](http://www.emmet-gray.com/Files/Applications/EdgeManageProgramFiles.zip)

Answer (score -1):

Here is a tip to help [export Edge favorites and import to Chrome](https://www.cyclonis.com/import-favorites-from-edge-to-chrome/) or any other browsers, but let's just take Chrome for example.

1. Export Edge favorites/bookmarks into an HTML file.
   Open **Microsoft Edge**, click the triple-dot button (menu) in the upper right corner and click **Settings**.  Click **Export to file** and choose where to save the **HTML file**.
2. Launch Google Chrome and import the file. Click the three-dot button in the upper right corner. Go to **Settings** and click **Import bookmarks and settings**. From the drop-down menu, select **Bookmarks HTML File**. Click Choose **File**, navigate to the HTML file with the exported favorites and double-click it.

Moments later, the blue tick should appear, and your Edge favorites should be available in Google Chrome.

Answer (score -1):

Click the Favorites Star and "Manage Favorites"
[Manage Favorites](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9ElFS.png)

select the folder you'd like to export, Then click the "..." three dots in the upper right corner and select "Export favorites"

[Export](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p2nmU.png)