# Import Favorite Bookmarks to Edge From Another Machine

Tags: desktop-computer, import, microsoft-edge, favorites

The problem is when copying files containing bookmarks from a machine with W10 Pro & Edge 38.14393.0.0 to another machine (W10 Home) with the same version of Edge, the bookmarks do not appear.
What has been done:

- Downloaded and ran NirSoft's great [ESE DB Viewer](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/ese_database_view.html) (pity this cannot modify records)
- Copied over the entire folder MicrosoftEdge_8wekyb3d8bbwe from the original machine (permissions were granted after cancelling COM Surrogate in Task Manager) to Appdata\Packages on the target machine.
- Copied the three files in DBStore over to AppData\Local\MicrosoftEdge\User\Default\DataStore\Data\nouser1\120712-0049\DBStore
- Started Edge, no bookmarks showed up. The favorites section of spartan.edb had been wiped.

At this stage Edge only imports bookmarks from IE or Chrome. It is possible to export the bookmarks from spartan.edb to a JSON comma delimited file, but it does not appear to be of the same format as the JSON Chrome Bookmarks file. Also tried both HTML exported formats from Nirsoft's viewer into Chrome,- again without success.

Also tried Emmet Gray's [Edge Manage](http://www.emmet-gray.com/Articles/EdgeManage.html), but there is an access violation on the Restore function in the target directory, even when run as Admin. Funny, as we are able to modify records directly from the UI and save there.

Ideally, Edge would want to maintain a backup of the favorites to a cloud, so a restore from there would be a trivial matter, in case of H/W failure.
Any idea of how one can copy the favorites from the original database?

Update: Did check out David Postill's answer [here](https://superuser.com/questions/1002351/add-bookmarks-to-microsoft-edge-manually?rq=1), but not sure if it is current, as there have been changes in the Edge FS since.

Comment: I'm very curious about the "access violation" when using EdgeManage... can you tell me more?

Comment: @Emmet. _Think_ I either zipped up spartan.edb or just selected it in the dialogue. Probably a no-no. At any rate, it looks like it's better to use your great program to export the Edge Favs to IE on the source machine first, rather than worry about copying stuff nested 15 folders deep. :)

Comment: ...or just use the EdgeManage import/export to the HTML-based "bookmarks" file.  That makes a very simple backup/import/transport option.

Answer (score 0):

The most practical solution is not to create bookmarks on this edition of Edge at all if intending to export the bookmarks to another location.
So for a new page to be bookmarked or a current bookmark to be updated, write an extension that saves the bookmark either to Chrome or IE Favorites- or both.
Chrome is preferred as IE does not (and probably will not) export bookmarks to Edge.

Consider a possible scenario with two machines with only one running Chrome. Let's call it C and the other NC (No Chrome)
To export Edge bookmarks from C to NC:

- On C: Import Edge bookmarks into Chrome. Import Chrome bookmarks into IE.
- On NC: Import IE bookmarks into Edge.

To export Edge bookmarks from NC to C (Not so easy unless Chrome was installed of course):

- Copy spartan.edb over to the C machine.
- On the C machine, use the ESE DB Viewer to export the records to a plain csv file, then, using something like Nirsoft's [CSV Fileview](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/csv_file_view.html) Choose Columns to select the url and url_name.
- Then copy the contents of each bookmark subfolder into a text editor and sort alphabetically. Assuming Chrome (or IE) had a previous version of the same set of bookmarks, one could manually update by comparison.

A tedious task at best, but an alternative as noted in an answer to this [question](https://superuser.com/questions/951506/how-to-export-favourites-bookmarks-from-microsoft-edge?rq=1), Firefox favorites can be exported into any browser.